# Why is NULL reads so high in my SQL trace?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have inserted data from a sql trace in a table and I have a problem interpreting the data in table.

In the attached image the reads related to my SP are very low but on the next line for a value of NULL in Text Data column the reads are very high.

How do i interpret this.? Why the NULL rows have so high read values?

Edit: I have updated the image file. Now it has all the column names for initial 10 rows of my trace I could not find any EventType column, but there is an EventClass column which has value : 15 for every NULL row.

### Screenshot

[image: Profiler Screenshot]

Comment: What event type are those rows?

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to include all the columns. There is no EventType, but some EventClass column. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [SQL Server Event Class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx). You determine the `EventType` by `EventClass` value. Some `EventClass` types come with a `NULL` value for `TextData`.

Also, here's a query that might help you out mapping the `EventClass` ID to the actual event type:

```
SELECT   te.name
FROM     dbo.Trace t 
         JOIN sys.trace_events te ON t.EventClass = te.trace_event_id
```

where `dbo.Trace` is the table where you save the EventClass values.

Comment: `select * from sys.trace_events where trace_event_id=15` indicates this event is `Audit Logout` so this is [just cumulative total of reads for the connection](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/b3ef2174-a6be-4bb1-9f6d-1568cd3a2c78/)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Seems that way, yes. Although, I couldn't find what EventClass 0 and 9999 are.

Comment: Maybe "Trace Start" and "Existing Connections"? Not sure what UI the OP is using that shows numbers rather than text descriptions.